# Partial reading and writing data via Spring Batch - OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, spring-batch, jvm-arguments

I'm running an application with spring batch jobs. When I try to collect and publish some data from one data source to another I get the following exception.

```
o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep -  Encountered an error executing step upload in job reviewsToYtBatchJob
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:59)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1967)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3401)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:483)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2266)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1485)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:856)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:126)
```

My questions are:

- **How to get heap size parameter?**
- **How fetch data partially?**

It works only in a small amount of data. I've also tried this:

```
reader.setFetchSize(CHUNK_SIZE); //JdbcCursorItemReader
uploadStep.chunk(CHUNK_SIZE);  //SimpleStepBuilder
```

CHUNK_SIZE tried from 100 to 10000 If I limit selected data with the size it works, heap size was not exceeded.

```
protected ItemReader<Review> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Review> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataScource);
        reader.setSql(
         //sql query
        );
        reader.setFetchSize(CHUNK_SIZE);
        reader.setRowMapper(
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Review(
                        rs.getLong("reviewId"),
                        //map data

                )
        );
        return reader;
    }

private ItemProcessor<Review, ReviewTo> processor() {
        return review -> new ReviewTo(
                //parameters
        );
    }
private ItemWriter<ReviewTo> writer() {
    return new ItemWriter<>(client);
}

private TaskletStep uploadStep() {
    SimpleStepBuilder<Review, ReviewTo> uploadStep = new SimpleStepBuilder<>(stepBuilderFactory.get("upload"));
    return uploadStep
            .chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job reviewsToYtBatchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME)
            .start(//generate table)
                    .build())
            .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("createTmpTable")
                    .tasklet(//step)
                    .build())
            .next(uploadStep())
            .next(stepBuilderFactory.get("moveTmpTableToDestination")
                    .tasklet(//step)
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not enough memory space. It worked with parameters CHUNK_SIZE = 100000 and -Xmx4g. There was a config file with arguments for virtual machine where I could increase heap size.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of chunk processing is to not load the entire data set in memory but do it in chunks. So using a chunk oriented step as you did is the way to go.

> How to get heap size parameter?

Well, that parameter is what you have passed to the JVM with `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. See default values in the documentation of your JVM.

> How fetch data partially?

When you set up a chunk oriented step, Spring Batch will do it automatically according to the chunkSize of your step and fetchSize of your `JdbcCursorItemReader`. BTW, I see you set the same value for those two parameters which is a good thing! Matching the fetchSize and chunkSize usually leads to better performance.

So I think your issue is not really an issue because it is normal that when increasing the chunk size, more items will be loaded in memory until you get an OOM error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I use a remote virtual machine, and want to know how I can learn values of this parameters not from documentation but actual.

Thank you for the comments about chunkSize and fetchSize. Looks like I just need choose a proper value for CHUNK_SIZE. Though I've tried different values from 10 up to 700000. The bigger value sooner it fails. I guess that is value is too big it might be a problem load all data at once and if value is too small it might be a lot of garbage is produced so GC is not able to deal with using available memory.